# reportPlaySeconds being called regardless of returned interval

Tags: sonos

I'm using some additional logic to skirt around this issue, but I've noticed `reportPlaySeconds` being called regardless of the `interval` value I return.

The [Result documentation](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/388) states:

> **interval string(128)** - Number of seconds to elapse before next report. Note:  A value of 0 indicates that no reporting after the start of playback of that track should be issued.

This is an example request request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
<SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <ns1:credentials>
        <ns1:deviceId>00-01-02-0A-0B-0C</ns1:deviceId>
        <ns1:deviceProvider>Sonos</ns1:deviceProvider>
        <ns1:sessionId>303-TEMP</ns1:sessionId>
    </ns1:credentials>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:reportPlaySeconds>
        <ns1:id>track_id</ns1:id>
        <ns1:seconds>0</ns1:seconds>
    </ns1:reportPlaySeconds>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

And the response:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://www.sonos.com/Services/1.1">
<SOAP-ENV:Body>
    <ns1:reportPlaySecondsResponse>
        <ns1:reportPlaySecondsResult>
            <ns1:interval>0</ns1:interval>
        </ns1:reportPlaySecondsResult>
    </ns1:reportPlaySecondsResponse>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

If I've understood the documentation correctly, returning **`<ns1:interval>0</ns1:interval>`** means `reportPlaySeconds` shouldn't be called again. I'm also using `setPlayedSeconds` to calculate more granular reporting, so additional `reportPlaySeconds` calls are unnecessary.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although the documentation does state you (the provider) can change the reporting interval by returning `interval` in the `reportPlaySecondsResult`, the feature is not enabled in firmware as of the latest release (Version 5.4, Build 29.5-91030, Released 13 July 2015).

As you have seen, the player continues to report on a fixed interval no matter what the value returned in `reportPlaySecondsResult`.

I've opened a ticket with the documentation team for an update.

Comment: Thanks! A value of 0 fails the self-test suite, so having this updated would be great.

Comment: @RichardThornton, that looks like a bug in the self-test if the documentation is correct. The documentation says returning 0 should turn off reporting for the given track so the self-test should accept that return value.

Comment: @RichardThornton, just wanted to let you know the [documentation for reportPlaySeconds](http://musicpartners.sonos.com/node/388) has been updated.

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem, player continues to report on fixed interval irrespective of the returned value, have you guys found any solution?

Comment: @Feroz, sorry to hear of your troubles. Please open a new question and link to this one. This was posted almost a year ago, the documentation has changed, and Sonos has had several firmware releases since this question was answered. You'll get a more accurate assessment of your particular issue this way. Thank you.